# Why does parseFloat(027) equals 23

Tags: javascript

I tested it in the chrome console and also in IE11.

```
parseFloat(27) => 27
parseFloat('27') => 27
parseFloat('027') => 27
```

but

```
parseFloat(027) => 23
parseFloat(0027) => 23
```

I guess is understanding it as an octal, but I didn't find any reference to that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Since I'm using it to secure a number which is a user input, how can I make certain that even with the preceding 0 it gets handled as a float?

Comment: It's not a behavior specific to `parseFloat`; it's a language-parsing behavior. Number tokens that begin with `0` are interpreted *by the parser that reads JavaScript code* as representing an octal value. Unless you're using `eval` somewhere (if so, you probably shouldn't), the user can't create a language-level octal number token. The user can only supply a string that will be held inside a variable, which will not be treated as an octal.

Comment: Since it's user input, shouldn't it always be a string? Also if you use `parseInt` you can set the base explicitly: `parseInt('027',10) == 27`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parseFloat` doesn't understand octal:

```
> parseFloat('027')
27
```

The problem is that you're feeding it a number, rather than a string. `027` is an octal numeric literal that evaluates to `23`; `parseFloat` doesn't know it ever looked like `027`. As long as you make sure to pass a string to the function, you shouldn't have any octal problems.

Answer (score 4):

"`027`" is the way you specify 27 octal in source code. Since you aren't going to let a user input your source code, there's nothing special you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does parseFloat(027) equals 23

The argument to `parseFloat()` is a string value, so a cast is performed on anything that's not a string; literal numbers such as `0x20` or `027` are normalized to the decimal system first.

That means `parseFloat(027)` is actually `parseFloat('23')`.

> how can I make certain that even with the preceding 0 it gets handled as a float?

By making sure the value you're passing to `parseFloat()` is a string value, because leading zeroes have no special meaning in `parseFloat()` (and `parseInt()` with a radix of 10).

Answer (score 0):

It's interpreting the input as octal. See [here](http://coderstoolbox.net/number/). If you enter '027' in the "Octal" field you'll see "23" output in the "Decimal" field.